# how to call a variable of another class without using objects or class methods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros

In my app,  there is a constant in a common class which defined as

`#define IMG_INIT_URL @"http://www.xxxx/index.php"`

Now i have a requirement of change it as a variable.But my problem is that i used this constant frequently in my code for example:

```
NSString *imgUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",IMG_INIT_URL,[[[storeDet objectForKey:@"store_imgurls"] objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"simg_imgurl"]];
```

When i changed it to a variable i have to retreive it through object or class method that requires a lot of editing in my code. So can i maintain the code as same as now(ie, accessing the variable without using object or class method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the define to

```
#define IMG_INIT_URL [UIApplication.sharedApplication imgInitURL]
```

and then add a `- (NSString *)imgInitURL` method in your UIApplication subclass or a UIApplication category. Or add the method to the application delegate if that is more convenient and modify the define accordingly.

Comment: `NSApplication`? In iOS? You probably mean `UIApplicationDelegate`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. one more thing, this is a root address. i have   some more urls defined as constants. now i defined them as static. can i defined them related with IMG_INIT_URL?

Comment: @manujmv: that depends on the context of the static variable declaration. If it is inside a method body the above should work. Otherwise it may be possible that the application object is not yet defined. In that case you could define a class method `+ (NSString *)imgInitURL` on some class, and change the define to `[MyClass imgInitURL]`. In that case you'd also need to include the `MyClass` header in your apps precompiled (.pch) header, so that the method definition is seen everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can always define it in `.pch` file which is normally found in `Supporting Files` folder, so you need use it where you want it. I also personally include some classes  which i need to use in different classes. Then, i don't need to include in every class that i use.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you define a property `imgURL` in a singleton class named `Constants`, you can do this:

```
#define IMG_INIT_URL [Constants sharedInstance].imgURL
```

Also, check out XCode's refactoring under `Edit` > `Refactor`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use NSUserDefault as below

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"http://www.xxxx/index.php" forKey:@"IMG_INIT_URL"];
```

and access it using whereevr you want.

```
 NSString *aReturnValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"IMG_INIT_URL"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through setting the variable in your AppDelegate Class. Create a variable in AppDelegate.h as given,

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *imageInitURL;
```

And synthesis that in AppDelegate .m file

```
@synthesize imageInitURL;
```

Then if you want to set the value initially, u can set that in "application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions" method

```
[self setImageInitURL:@"http://www.xxxx/index.php"];
```

Then you can access this from any class through appDelegate shared Instance like given,

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate imageInitURL];
```

The same way you can set new value to this from any class like given

```
[appDelegate setImageInitURL:@"your new URL"];
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: thx for your reply. but in ur answer, i have to change the code whereever i used this constant. my question is how to avoid that?

Comment: #define is not constant. Its just replacing the name with what you defined for that.